# Electron.js: How can I achieve a reactive variable update in the preload.js file?

Tags: node.js, electron, svelte

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
/* ** preload.js ** */
const {contextBridge} = require('electron');
const os = require('os');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('system', {
   freeMemory: () => os.freemem()
});
```

> How can I expose freeMemory every time this value changes?

I save this freeMemory value to the svelte store

```
/* ** store.js ** */
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

export const freeMemory = writable(window.system.freeMemory());
```

I will use the `freeMemory` variable from svelte store in the svelte component as follows:

```
/* ** App.svelte ** */
<script>
   import {freeMemory} from 'store.js';
</script>

<main>
   Current available memory: { $freeMemory } bytes
</main>
```

This example works well. But the only thing that doesn't work properly is updating the `freeMemory` value in the svelte store in real time. `Electron.js` probably gets the value for the `freeMemory` variable only once and then does not update the value after that.
Is there a way to update this value every time it changes in real time?

I code in electron.js for a short time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory changes pretty much all the time, so you can just update it in an interval. The way `freeMemory` is defined you should be able to just call it again:

```js
export const freeMemory = writable(window.system.freeMemory());
setInterval(() => freeMemory.set(window.system.freeMemory()), 1000);
```

(Can be optimized to just export the `subscribe` function, as this should not be writable outside.)

Comment: This was an option I was thinking about, but I was wondering if there was a "better" solution. @HB

Answer (score 1):

Great question. I'm trying to achieve something similar using Pinia and VueJS. I can't access my Pinia stores in Electron before my render process with my single page app is loaded and Pinia is fully registered onto it, so I've been trying to figure out a workaround similar to yours.

I also considered the `setInterval` hack as mentioned in the other answer, but I'm not crazy about that. So, instead, I'm just moving my Pinia store to a javascript module and exporting accessor methods.

For example, something like this, in a file named `someModule.js`:

```html
let dynamicVariable = null;

// value changes at some point

function getDynamicVariable() {
  return dynamicVariable;
}

module.exports = {
  getDynamicVariable
}
```